# Win206 error in python

Tags: python, c, pycparser

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python34\vp\pycparser\__init__.py", line 44, in preprocess_file
universal_newlines=True)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
  startupinfo)
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vp/task3.py", line 250, in <module>
   debugs(c_file,root,"vp/log.txt",inc)
  File "vp/task3.py", line 86, in debugs
   ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True,cpp_path='gcc',cpp_args=['-E','-      std=
  c99','-nostdinc', include])
  File "C:\Python34\vp\pycparser\__init__.py", line 86, in parse_file
   text = preprocess_file(filename, cpp_path, cpp_args)
 File "C:\Python34\vp\pycparser\__init__.py", line 49, in preprocess_file
('Original error: %s' % e))
RuntimeError: Unable to invoke 'cpp'.  Make sure its path was passed    correctly
Original error: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long

 include=incl
 ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True,cpp_path='gcc',cpp_args=['-E','-     std=c99','-nostdinc', include])
```

I am passing a list of include directories that have big paths , to the cpp_args in pycparser , these are some of the errors i have encountered , any solution to the above problem or i need to include a raw string of include directories?

Comment: This is a Windows error, `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE`, not an internal python error.

Comment: So how do i avoid it anyway?

Comment: how are you creating the `include` variable?

Comment: using python os.walk() method i am traversing through all subdir's and putting them in a list and that list is include variable.@AnandSKumar

Comment: Check the length of the filenames.  Windows error messages might mislead sometimes, but they don't lie.